# Flutter - showDatePicker set first day of week to Monday

Tags: flutter

I am using the flutter `showDatePicker` widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html

When the date picker popup loads by default the start of the week is Sunday, I would like to change this to Monday.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

```dart
Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _selectedDate,
      firstDate: firstDate,
      lastDate: lastDate,
      locale: const Locale('en', 'GB'),
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != _selectedDate) {
      // update the calendar slider with new date
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = picked.add(Duration(hours: 1));
      });
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add a `locale` that uses Monday as the first day of the week, for example:

```
  Future<DateTime> selectedDate = showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    locale: const Locale('en', 'GB'),
    // etc
```

You have to add the localization library too, as described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization), adding this to your `MaterialApp`:

```
  localizationsDelegates: GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegates,
  supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('en', 'US'),
    const Locale('en', 'GB'),
  ],
```

Comment: Hi,

thank you for your reply, I have tried the above code however no changes are taking place.

Comment: Add the localization package to your app

Comment: Anyway to change this without adding something that can affect the whole app?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To start from Monday, you need to override the locale of the child widget.
Which means wrapping the date picker widget into **Localizations.override** constructor and specifying a locale, e.g: **Locale('en', 'GB')**

```
      // Add the following code into the Parent widget
      child: Localizations.override(
        context: context,
        locale: const Locale('en', 'GB'), // This would change the week days order.
        // Using a Builder to get the correct BuildContext.
        // Alternatively, you can create a new widget and Localizations.override
        // will pass the updated BuildContext to the new widget.
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            // An example for an internationalized Material widget.
            return CalendarDatePicker( ... );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

More info on [Flutter doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#overriding-the-locale)